# How to make a standalone app like a website form?

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-forms

I would like to create a small app that would be like a form on a website, but just for local files. I'm not really sure where to start (Django or other) or what to use, but I'd like to start with the GUI.

What would be the best way to create a program like this? Can I use Django to create a form that would not be used in a browser and without a server?

Comment: Django is a python server framework.  If you want something that's desktop-application-esque you can use PyQt or other python GUI frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you want to create UI for a Form. Also, you don't want to use browser. Then you have lots of options. `Django` is web-framework. You can avoid it. Simply create a UI with `WxPython` or `PyQt` (I recommend to use this) or `TkInter` etc. Do a google search for tutorials.

Comment: Thanks! PyQt looks really useful. Here is a link to my next question, if you can help :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051403/how-to-save-a-form-from-qt-designer-as-a-standalone-app

Answer (score 0):

Use [Python Webkit](http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/) and you can even create a website and render through it.